# On the conditional probability of a random sequence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let us take a infinite random sequence of positive (base $10$) integer $s_1s_2\cdots s_n$ (a sequence is *random* if for every $n$, all possible strings of lenght $n$ long have natural density $1/10^n$). Is it true the following statement?

A sequence is random in the sense of above **if and only if**, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$
\mathbb{P}(s_n=S_n|s_1\cdots s_{n-1}=S_1\cdots S_{n-1})=1/10,
$$
for all $S_i \in \{ 0,1,\dots, 9\}$, with $i=1,\dots,n$.

One direction is almost trivial, ideed if the sequence is random then, by the rule of conditional probability we have:
$$
\mathbb{P}(s_n=S_n|s_1\cdots s_{n-1}=S_1\cdots S_{n-1})=\frac{\mathbb{P}(s_1\cdots s_{n}=S_1\cdots S_{n})}{\mathbb{P}(s_1\cdots s_{n-1}=S_1\cdots S_{n-1})}=1/10.
$$

For the other implication, I think that if there exists a number, for which

$$
\mathbb{P}(s_2=S_2)=\alpha \neq 1/10
$$

we can conclude immediately that
$$
\mathbb{P}(s_2=S_2|s_1=S_1)={\mathbb{P}(s_2=S_2)}=\alpha \neq 1/10,
$$
because the two events are independent.

Moreover, if we call $\tilde{n}$ the  the minimum $n \ge 2$ such that there exists a string $\tilde{s}_1\cdots \tilde{s}_{\tilde{n}}$ of size $\tilde{n}$, for which
$$
\mathbb{P}(s_1\cdots s_{\tilde{n}}=\tilde{s}_1\cdots \tilde{s}_{\tilde{n}})=\beta \neq \frac{1}{10^{\tilde{n}}}.
$$
Thus, we have a contradiction, indeed

\begin{align*}
 \mathbb{P}(s_{\tilde{n}}=\tilde{s}_{\tilde{n}} \ | \ s_1\cdots s_{\tilde{n}-1}=\tilde{s}_1\cdots \bar{s}_{\tilde{n}-1})
 =&\frac{\mathbb{P}(s_1\cdots s_{\tilde{n}}=\tilde{s}_1\cdots \tilde{s}_{\tilde{n}})}{\mathbb{P}(s_1\cdots s_{\tilde{n}-1}=\tilde{s}_1\cdots \tilde{s}_{\tilde{n}-1})}\\
 =&\frac{\beta}{10^{-(\tilde{n}-1)}}\neq \frac{1}{10}.
\end{align*}

I'm not so sure about this second step.